# Updating UITableViewController on back navigation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` listing the api fetched list of projects. And another ViewController which handles the creation of new project. After the project is saved succesfully. When I press the default back button on navigation bar to get the list of projects. That list isn't updated (requires an app restart to show latest results

`viewDidLoad` method currently handles the fetching projects api call.

Comment: move API work in viewWillAppear .

Comment: This is happening because viewDidLoad is called only once, when the view controller is first initialised. call the API in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad, and reload the table view.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu : If calling api in `viewWillAppear` then no need to call in `viewDidload`.

Comment: @Lion You are right that's why I said call the API in viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad. I just mentioned viewDidLoad functionality for better understanding.

Comment: @PallaviSrikhakollu : your edited comment is ok! older one was wrong!

Comment: Thank you all, moving the API call in `viewWillAppear` solved the issue. And I understand the reason.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is this (in your UIViewController that has a UITableView). You don't have to worry about what happens at cell-level at this point.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; // to reload selected cell
}
```

Just add the code above to your controller, and you'll see that the right thing happens when you come back from your second view. The call to reloadData tells the table view that it needs to refresh its cells from your model, and everything else follows nicely.